# Remove Configuration from SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I've faced multiple times with the scenario, when **I need to remove some Configuration from SpringBootApplication in the test scope**, without changing the source scope, and I can't find the correct solution.

Let's say I have some SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

There are multiple configurations in the base package, including this one, which creates Hazelcast client and expects to connect to some existing hazelcast instance:

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfig {

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        ClientConfig config = ...
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }
}
```

**Now, what I want to do, is to create some SandboxLocalApplicationLauncher in the test scope, which would run Application with some pre-existing configs for local environment.** But I don't have Hazelcast cluster in the local environment, so I want to be able to override HazelcastInstance bean, something like this:

```
@Import(SandboxLocalApplicationLauncher.IsolatedLocalConfig.class)
public class SandboxLocalApplicationLauncher {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SandboxLocalApplicationLauncher.class);
        app.setAdditionalProfiles("local");
        app.run(args);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan(basePackage= "...",
        excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = Application.class),
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = HazelcastConfig.class),
        }
    )
    @Profile("local")
    public class IsolatedLocalConfig {
    
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public HazelcastInstance localHazelcastInstance() {
            return myCustomHazelcastMock...;
        }

}
```

The problem is, that even if I'm able to use my local hazelcast instance as a primary bean, the one from the source context is still initializing, which results in an error and failure of the whole application.

Whatever I do (trying to configure ComponentScan with exclude filters), I'm not able to get rid of the original HazelcastConfig or the original HazelcastInstance bean creation.

The only work-around I could achieve is to use ConditionalOnProperty for HazelcastConfig, but I don't want to introduce such conditions for Prod code, I want it to be overriden only in the test context.

Any suggestions how I can exclude Configuration?

Comment: Just add `@Profile("!local")` to your `HazelcastConfig` class and it should do the trick